# how can i listen to document body using reacts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

i intend to convert this vanilla javaScript code to react. below are the html and javaScripts codes...

**html cod**

```
<div class="middle">
                <img src="images/vr-iootz.jpg" draggable="false"/>
            </div>



<div class="scroller scroller-middle">
                <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:rgb(24,24,62)"/></svg>
            </div>
```

**Vanilla code**

```
let active = false;
let scrollerMiddle = document.querySelector('.scroller-middle');
let scrollerTop = document.querySelector('.scroller-top');



scrollerMiddle.addEventListener('mousedown',function(){
    active = "middle";
    scrollerMiddle.classList.add('scrolling');
    });
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
    active = false;
    scrollerMiddle.classList.remove('scrolling');
    });


   document.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left; scrollIt(x); });
```

now of course i know that i can convert part of the above code using react event handler method as seen below

```
const divRef = useRef(null);

  const hleMouseDown = () => {
    active = "middle";
    divRef.current.classList.add("scrolling");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="middle">
        <img src="images/vr-iootz.jpg" draggable="false" alt="/" />
      </div>

      <div
        ref={divRef}
        className="scroller-middle"
        onMouseDown={hleMouseDown}
      >
        <svg
          className="scroller__thumb"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="100"
          height="100"
          viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        >
          <polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
          <polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" fill="rgb(24,24,62)" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**however, i am finding the body manipulation difficult and the other querySelector too as seen below**

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
    active = false;
    scrollerMiddle.classList.remove('scrolling');
    });


   document.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left; scrollIt(x); });
```

so any tip will be appreciated

so , basically i can say that the area of concern is how to add the wrapper css and how to use useRef for the body calling in react..

i was able to call them using vanilla

Answer (score 0):

In React you need to use a `state` for `active` because the value of a variable would be lost after a re-render:

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
```

So now that we have a state, we can change it when mouse is down:

```
  const hleMouseDown = () => {
    setActive(true);
  };
```

We can also react to state change in `useEffect` to create the side effect of adding and removing an event handler to the document. The event handler would update the `active` state, and react to the `active` state as well:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(active) {
      const handler = () => {
        setActive(false);
      };
    
      document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', handler);

      return () => {
        document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', handler);
      };
    }
  }, [active]);
```

And we can also use the `active` state to add/remove the class to the scroller element:

```
  <div
    className={`scroller-middle ${active ? 'scrolling' : ''}`}
    onMouseDown={hleMouseDown}
  >
```

Full code:

```
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const hleMouseDown = () => {
    setActive(true);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(active) {
      const handler = () => {
        setActive(false);
      };
    
      document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', handler);

      return () => {
        document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', handler);
      };
    }
  }, [active]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="middle">...</div>

      <div
        className={`scroller-middle ${active ? 'scrolling' : ''}`}
        onMouseDown={hleMouseDown}
      >
        <svg>...</svg>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: A lot but confuse, i think it might be better to provide the link to the original project I am trying to covert in my git respiratory…  https://github.com/okikiola12/vanilla-project

Comment: In the example I've created there's a single component that handles a single item. If you want "top", "middle" and "bottom" render the component 3 times, and pass different text/icon/etc... Each instance would have it's own `active` state, and would attach the document event handler for itself when needed.

Comment: again, I understand the reason for the useState, however, there is a need to make the middle class active when the function is triggered and
with the divRef nested in the function for adding the CSS scroll effects, while,
this can be **document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', handler);** nested in the useEffects ?

Comment: Thanks so far, i have managed to find a solution.
this **document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', handler);**
should be rewritten as **window.addEventListener()**

instead

Comment: One more thing, how can i change the position of the clip-path to right instead of the left...

here is the code 

`const setPosi = useCallback((x) => {
    const { left, width } = imageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const handleWidth = hdleRef.current.offsetWidth;

    if (x >= left && x <= width + left - hdleWidth) {
      hdleRef.current.style.left = `${((x - left) / width) * 100}%`;
      imageRef.current.style.clipPath = `inset(0 ${
        100 - ((x - left) / width) * 100
      }% 0 0)`;
    }
  }, []);`

thanks